# vue.js alert pops instead of console.log or anything else

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I was working on a Follow button and while trying to get things clear I used alert when I clicked my button, then I changed it to console.log instead of alert but still alert kept popping up. Then I did a text change instead of this but the alert keeps on popping. I already tried clearing cache or fresh migrate but still not working.

File: Follow.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" @click="followUser" v-text="buttonText"></button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: ['userId','follows'],

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        data: function () {
            return {
                status: this.follows
            }
        },
    
        methods: {
            followUser(){
                axios.post('/follow/' + this.userId)
                .then(response =>{
                    this.status = ! this.status;
                });
            ; 
        },
        computed: {
            buttonText(){
                return (this.status) ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow';
            }
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```

File: index.blade.php

```
...ect...
 <follow-me user-id="{{ $user->id }}" follows="{{ $follows }}"> </follow-me>
...ect...
```

File: ProfilesController.php

```
public function index(User $user)
    {     
        $follows = (auth()->user()) ? auth()->user()->following->contains($user->id) : false;
        
        return view('profiles.index', compact('user', 'follows'));
    }
```

File: FollowsController.php

```
public function store(User $user){
        return auth()->user()->following()->toggle($user->profile);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `npm run watch`?

Comment: @Shizzen83 ohh thank you, but now that I did that bc I had forgot, it shows no text on my button, just a tiny blue button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `npm run watch` , it will recompile your whole asset( any `js`  or  `css` file).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run `npm run watch` (or `dev`) to update your built assets.

About your button, replace

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" @click="followUser" v-text="buttonText"></button>
```

By

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" @click="followUser">{{ buttonText }}</button>
```

Comment: Actually, npm run watch (which I had forgotten) helped, but one thing that I messed up was that I used 'computed' in the wrong place, I had to put it out 'export default' and now it is working. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted please.

Comment: I tried to do that but it said u have to wait 5 mins and I forgot bc I was doing some coding. Now I did it.